# how to GET and search response contain the file then proceed to next HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario that

```
1. user upload a file - system process take 10mins -
2. then the user can transfer the file
```

I cannot do load test in a Thread - #1 then #2 because of the processing time (#2 is performing too quickly before the file is ready for transfer).

I am thinking to keep sending GET requests and finding the response containing the file name then proceeding to #2.

I can only use GET API to get a list of files (API does not support specific file search, the GET return list of file in response)

is that a good approach? how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to wait until the uploaded file appears in the list of files from the API. The output of the API can be parsed using i.e. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

Check out [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) for more comprehensive information and example configuration.

Comment: is this design alright ? 1. POST file 2. GET list + json extractor to watch file name is ABC (how to do so?) . where should I insert the while controller with condition = file name ABC (at the GET request or the next POST transfer request?)

Comment: Next to POST, and GET request should be the child of the While Controller